# sed:command not found, after if statement

Tags: bash, sed

I've started shell scripting yesterday, so please be patient! :-)

I have this piece of code:

```
for FILEOUT in *.out
do
if [[ $FILEOUT == a*.out ]]; then
    PATH="./Scalars/"
elif [[ $FILEOUT == v*.out ]]; then
    PATH="./Vectors/"
elif [[ $FILEOUT == t*.out ]]; then
    PATH="./Tensors/"
fi

echo sunday | sed 's/day/night/'
done
```

(I know the last statement is stupid, but if I can't get that to work, there's no question of doing more complicated things!)
I get this error:

```
createpyfiles.sh: line 17: sed: command not found
```

Needless to say, sed is working perfectly if I slightly change the script to, for example, echo a word instead of assigning a PATH, and, more broadly, in every other context.

Can you please help understand why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `which sed` ? what output? because you change `PATH` before `sed` and don't use `PATH` here try with else like `MYPATH` or `PATH="$PATH:/mydir"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you changed `PATH`, it contained `/bin` and/or `/usr/bin`, where `sed` is located. After you remove `sed`'s location from `PATH`, of course the shell can't find it any more. If you want to add to `PATH` you need to do something like

```
PATH="$PATH:your/dir/here"
```

Comment: @user2669155 or you will have to explicitly mention the full path like /bin/sed instead of sed.

Comment: If you were trying to use `PATH` as something other than the list of directories where the shell looks for commands, yes that was a really bad variable name.

Comment: @user2669155 FYI by UNIX convention all-upper-case variable names are used only for exported variables which helps avoid issues like this. Had you followed that convention your variable would have been named `path` instead of `PATH` and you wouldn't have had a problem.

Comment: I'll look through the UNIX conventions then! I thought all the variables were given capitalised names by convention.

Comment: @EdMorton ...except in zsh where the lowercase `$path` variable is magically tied to the `$PATH` environment variable. (It provides a way to manipulate `$PATH` as an actual array). In the csh family, tcsh has a similar feature.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley thanks for the info and - ugh! Never used it but I expected better from zsh. By the way, 30 years ago I played a curses-based game called "hunt the Wumpus" - my apologies :-).

Comment: @EdMorton I played a version of Hunt The Wumpus from one of those books you used to get with BASIC programs that you could type in and run. And I like `$path` - array operations are cleaner than colon-separated-string manipulation

Answer (score 0):

you must put `sunday` between quote marks in `echo` command :

```
echo "sunday" | sed 's/day/night/'
```

Comment: Nope, it works all the same, it's what Wumpus and JKB said: I was changing the PATH! Thanks anyway!